# Receber id na modal para excluir registro

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma pagina chamada `produtos.php`, onde listo todos produtos do meu banco de dados, cada produto esta em uma table e cada um tem seu respectivo botão de detalhes,editar e excluir, eu consigo passar o *id* para meu botão de exclui mas não consigo pegar ele no *modal*.

modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Excluir Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Deseja realmente excluir este item? <span class="nome"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delete">Sim</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">N&atilde;o</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Não entendo muito de JS

```
$('.modal').on('click', function () {
    var nome = $(this).data('nome'); 
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
    $('span.nome').text(nome + ' (id = ' + id + ')'); 
    $('.delete').attr('href', 'apagar.php?id=' + id); 
    $('#delete-modal').modal('show'); 

});
```

HTML/php do botão que abre a modal:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"     href="apagar.php?id=<?php echo   $linha['id_produto']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-nome="<?php echo $linha['nome'] ?>" data-id="<?php echo $linha['id_produto'] ?>" data-target="#delete-modal">Excluir</a>
```

Este é o meu botão.

Comment: o Botao de dentro da modal não pega o id

Comment: Eu acho que o que está mal é que tu está a colocar o evento click na modal, e acho que é para ser no botão que abre a modal, depois desde que os atributos data existam e estejam nos elementos certos nao vejo razão para não dar. Ajudaria se pusesses um exemplo de duas ou tres linhas de html dessa listagem de produtos

Comment: '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"  href="apagar.php?id=<?php echo $linha['id_produto']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-nome="<?php echo $linha['nome'] ?>" data-id="<?php echo $linha['id_produto'] ?>" data-target="#delete-modal">Excluir</a>'    

este é o meu botao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta o seguinte:

```
$('a[data-target="#delete-modal"]').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var nome = $(this).data('nome'); var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('span.nome').text(nome + ' (id = ' + id + ')');
    $('.delete').attr('href', 'apagar.php?id=' + id);
    $('#delete-modal').modal('show');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ok muito obrigado, Depois desta edição esta a funcionar, agora como eu pego o id na pagina de excluir

Comment: Marque a resposta @fabricio...

Comment: @Fabricio fazes, $_GET['id']

Comment: quando especiono elemento ele mostra o id no href, mas se clico no botao de confirmar na modal nada acontece

Comment: @Fabricio troca esse botao por <a>...</a>, em vez de button